# jsonschema for a map stored as an array [key1, val1, key2, val2.....]

Tags: jsonschema

Is it possible to create a json schema for an array with undefined length (besides it always being an even number of elements) that captures a map stored as an array?

i.e. as described in title [key1, val1, key2, val2.....]

it seems that the only option for an array of an undetermined length is to have a single item "type" (though that type could conceptually be a oneOf type).  However, that wouldn't enforce ordering of key/val schema restrictions.  While it would validate valid uses, it would also validate invalid uses.

if I knew how long the array would be, I could just enforce it by specifying the types for all keys and values in their respective positions, but that's not the case here.

Yes, it would be nice if the api worked off a map/object instead of an array in this location, but this is an old api that I'm trying to create a json schema for, so it probably can't be changed.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't something JSON Schema is capable of expressing.